# Javascript dot function with event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, dom-events

### Question

How do I create a custom javascript dot function that does the same thing as the following code in jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", ".someClass", function() {
   // code goes here
});
```

I'd like to declare it like this:

```
$(".someClass").onClick(function () {
   // code goes here
});
```

It needs to:

- work with dynamically created elements (hence jQuery .on() instead of .click())
- work with computer clicks as well as touch taps
- ideally, but not mandatorily, it would be written in pure javascript (no jQuery in the prototype itself, but can still be accessed through jQuery)

### What I've Tried

```
Object.prototype.onClick = function() {
   $(document).on('click touchstart', this, arguments);
};
```

But I receive the following error in chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function

I think I'm declaring it incorrectly, and perhaps that this is also not the correct way to access events in javascript.

Comment: why `dot` ? Is this a requirement ? because `$(blah).on` is not against each element.

Comment: I would argue against trying to do something like this.  Obscuring the delegate nature of the `on(event, selector, handler)` as a normal event binding is bound to cause confusion with future developers.  EDIT: And given that if it is, indeed, suppossed to work as a delegate, if the `.someClass` does not exist, what would you bind to?  Always bind to body?

Comment: @Taplar I think what he is really after is `event delegation`. jQuery obsures how its done and makes it look like a binding method.

Comment: @Bibberty - we don't know what the OP wants other than a customized way to do something very simply done with standard JS.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - "work with dynamically created elements (hence jQuery .on() instead of .click())"

Comment: @Bibberty - and this: _How do I create a custom javascript dot function that does the same thing as the following code in jQuery_ so the OP needs to cut-n-paste the plain ole JavaScript out of the jQuery source code and use that . [From Line 41 here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js) :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn he certainly could copy jQuery. Always an option.

Comment: @Taplar at the moment I'm the only one doing web development at my place of business. Regarding future developers: it seems like ``.onClick`` wouldn't be unlike one of the many other functions that jQuery programmers are used to. I see it as a matter of familiarization rather than confusion--as would be the case with any new developer on-boarding.

Comment: Thanks gents for looking at this for me. My javascript knowledge is pretty trapped inside of jQuery's ecosystem, which makes it tough to know what operations are actually available to me. Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for **Event Delegation** this allows you too dynamically add elements and still have them respond to click.

```js
const getDiv = (name) => {
  if (Array.isArray(name) === false) name = [name];
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  name.forEach(n => div2.classList.add(n));
  div2.innerText = `${name}`;
  return div2;
};

const makeDivs = () => {
  const div = document.querySelector('#main');

  const {
    dataset: {
      count: x
    }
  } = div;

  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    div.appendChild(getDiv('div2'));
    div.appendChild(getDiv('div3'));
    div.appendChild(getDiv(['div2', 'div3']));
  }
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({
  target
}) => {
  if (target.matches('.div2')) console.log('You clicked a DIV2');

  if (target.matches('.div3')) console.log('You clicked a DIV3 !!')

  if (target.matches('button')) makeDivs();

});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main' data-count="10">

</div>
<button>Click Me!!!</button>
```

Wrapping this up into a custom function.

NOTE: I changed `selector` param to be an array, this allows you to pass complex selectors e.g. `div.myClass li:hover`

```js
const getDiv = (name) => {
  if (Array.isArray(name) === false) name = [name];
  let div2 = document.createElement('div');
  name.forEach(n => div2.classList.add(n));
  div2.innerText = `${name}`;
  return div2;
};

const makeDivs = () => {
  const div = document.querySelector('#main');

  const {
    dataset: {
      count: x
    }
  } = div;

  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    div.appendChild(getDiv('div2'));
    div.appendChild(getDiv('div3'));
    div.appendChild(getDiv(['div2', 'div3']));
  }
};

document.on = (eventType, selector, callback) => {
  const events = eventType.split(' ');
  const selectors = (Array.isArray(selector)) ? selector : [selector];
  events.forEach(event => { document.addEventListener(event, (e) => {
      if(selectors.some(s => e.target.matches(s))) callback(e);
    });
  });
};

// Convenience method.
document.onClick = (selector, callback) => document.on('click', selector, callback);

// Simple
document.on('click', 'button', () => makeDivs());
document.on('click', '.div2', ({target}) => console.log('You clicked a DIV2'));

// Multi Event
document.on('click touchstart', '.div3', () => console.log('You clicked a DIV3'));

// Multi selectors
document.on('click', ['.div2', '.div3'], ({target}) => console.log('You clicked. !!'));

document.onClick('div', ({target}) => console.log('A Click Event!!'));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main' data-count="10">

</div>
<button>Click Me!!!</button>
```

Comment: @RandyCasburn whose rule is that :)

Comment: Thanks for doing this for me @Bibberty. Two questions regarding: (1) Does this work with touch taps as well as computer clicks? (2) Is there no way to format like jQuery's ``selector.event(function);`` format? It can only be done with ``document.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {function});``?

Comment: My main motivation in asking was to contain the necessary functionality in a neat package. I use the same ``$(document).on("click touchstart", "element", function() {});`` all over the place. It works perfectly fine, but I'm inclined to try to lessen the verbiage.

Comment: You can use 'touchstart' as well and this will work yes. You can also scope the listener to an element. Let me update for that.

Comment: Let me know when you do. I'll be monitoring my notifications.

Comment: Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a `.onClick` jQuery method

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  onClick: function(sel, cb) {
    return this.on('touchstart click', sel, function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') cb.apply(this, arguments);
    })
  }
});



$(document).onClick('.someClass', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.type)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="someClass">CLICK ME</p>
```

Or this simpler variant:

```
$.fn.onClick = function(sel, cb) {
  return this.on('touchstart click', sel, cb);
};

$(document).onClick('.someClass', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(ev.type)
});
```

Comment: You have half of it! I was trying to avoid typing out ``$(document)`` for each selection and just have it as ``$(".someClass").onClick(function(){});`` while still accounting for ``$(document)`` in order to select dynamically-added elements. Is there any way to get it to that stage? Thanks so much for taking the time to help!